# How to show a modal window in windows 10 universal app?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10

When I use Mail univesal app in windows 10, when i add an account (setting->accounts->add account), it seems popup a modal window to choose an account. I try to use MessageDialog, but i can't put any custom content into it.

**EDIT** : this is the screenshot
[image: screenshot]

Is someone knows how to implement it or there is some api can do it?

**Note:** When this window open, you even can't Minimize/Maximize/Close the main Window. So, it is definitely a modal window.

Answer (score 21):

I haven't used it myself yet but i believe you're looking for ContentDialog api.

```
var dialog = new ContentDialog() {
    Title = "Lorem Ipsum",
    MaxWidth = this.ActualWidth // Required for Mobile!
    Content = YourXamlContent
};


dialog.PrimaryButtonText = "OK";
dialog.IsPrimaryButtonEnabled = false;
dialog.PrimaryButtonClick += delegate {
};

var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

[image: content dialog]

msdn guidlines for dialogs: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx)

msdn ContentDialog API:  [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn997764.aspx#examples)

Answer (score 5):

You can easily create a new view like this, for example in your `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public static async Task<bool> TryShowNewWindow<TView>(bool switchToView)
{
    var newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
    int newViewId = 0;
    await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        var frame = new Frame();
        frame.Navigate(typeof(TView), null);
        Window.Current.Content = frame;

        newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    });
    var viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
    if (switchToView && viewShown)
    {
        // Switch to new view
        await ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(newViewId);
    }
    return viewShown;
}
```

For further information, take a look at those two guides:

- [Guidelines for multiple windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn434070.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Quickstart: Creating multiple windows for an app (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn582023.aspx)

Comment: I know, and I have tried, but the new windows is not a modal window.

Comment: @tao Well, you didn't ask for a modal window.

Comment: I'm sorry, The mail app looks like popup a modal window, do you know how to implement it? thanks!

Comment: @tao The mail app doesn't use modal dialogs. Extract from the link I provided: _The Mail app uses multiple windows. A user can view messages in the main app window or open a new window. This is useful when, for example, a user wants to compose a new message, **but use the main window to search for other messages at the same time**._. You should use modal dialogs only for `When the user's security might be compromised`, `When the user is about to permanently alter a valuable asset`, `When the user is about to delete a valuable asset` or `To confirm an in-app purchase`!

Comment: This is not a MODAL solution.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT Indeed. And the initial question, without edits, didn't request a modal solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Template10 project template, you can use the ModalDialog control : https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Docs-%7C-Controls#modaldialog